# How to avoid duplicate INSERTs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a `LeaveCounter` table like such :

```
Login | ActivityId | Value | Date
```

And when I load my page it fills it up with a new list, but I am looking for a way to avoid duplicate INSERTs.

Here is my SQL Server 2008 statement with the variables :

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO LeaveCounter VALUES ('" + employees[y] + "', '" + ActivityId[z] + "', 0 , " + yearlist[i] + ")";
```

Or simply :

```
INSERT INTO LeaveCounter VALUES (LOGIN, ACTIVITYID, 0, DATE)
```

How may I alter this call to make it so that it won't insert twice a row such as :

```
chris | 2 | 0 | 2015
```

So that It will add any new members of my list and simply skip existing ones?

Comment: Make unique index on those columns

Comment: Write a stored-procedure. You should also create a unique index with the relevant columns.

Comment: Then I will learn about stored-procedures, but what call should I use to see if the INSERT is a duplicate?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Insert if not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971680/sql-server-insert-if-not-exist)