# Using "BEGIN" keyword improperly

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am getting an error in the code below. I have added an arror `<------` where the problem is.

The error message says that a `THEN` is expected, but when I use `THEN`, then it says that a `BEGIN` is expected.

```
Error(27,6): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:     then and or The symbol "then" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue. 
Error(30,6): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:     , ; return returning
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE "sp_updateUserPassword"(newUserPwd IN VARCHAR2, curIsoUserUID IN NUMBER)
IS

curUserID NUMBER;
userDateCreated DATE;
oldUserPwd VARCHAR2(255);

BEGIN   
  
  SELECT ISOUID INTO curUserID FROM ISOUSERS WHERE ISOUID=curIsoUserUID;
  SELECT DATECREATE INTO userDateCreated FROM ISOUSERS WHERE ISOUID=curIsoUserUID;
  SELECT PASSWORD INTO oldUserPwd FROM ISOUSERS WHERE ISOUID=curIsoUserUID;
  
  IF(newUserPwd = oldUserPwd)
    THEN
      raise_application_error(-20000, 'The new password must be different from the previous password');
      RETURN;
  END IF;
    
  IF NOT EXISTS
                (
                  SELECT ISOUID 
                  FROM OLDUSERPASSWORDS 
                  WHERE ISOUID=curIsoUserUID
                )
     
     BEGIN           <------------ Error is here
        INSERT INTO OLDUSERPASSWORDS(ISOUID, DATECREATE, DATELASTCHANGE, CURRENTPASS, OLDPASS) 
        VALUES(curUserID, userDateCreated, SYSDATE, newUserPwd, oldUserPwd)
     END;
       

/*raise_application_error(-20000, 'TEST');*/
END "sp_updateUserPassword";
```

### Update

Corrected the code, so it now looks like this:

```
   IF NOT EXISTS
                (
                  SELECT ISOUID 
                  FROM OLDUSERPASSWORDS 
                  WHERE ISOUID=curIsoUserUID
                )
    THEN     
      BEGIN           
          INSERT INTO OLDUSERPASSWORDS(ISOUID, DATECREATE, DATELASTCHANGE, CURRENTPASS, OLDPASS) 
          VALUES(curUserID, userDateCreated, SYSDATE, newUserPwd, oldUserPwd)
      END;
  END IF;
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error(30,7): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Error(31,7): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:     ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
```

Perhaps it's just a minor error that I am missing?

Comment: If one of these answers solved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as accepted to let the community know this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

## PL/SQL Syntax Error for [IF THEN ELSE](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS388)

Correct syntax is:

```
IF condition THEN
  statements
END IF;
```

Your code is effectively:

```
IF condition THEN
  BEGIN
    statements
  END;
```

#### Corrected

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT ISOUID 
    FROM OLDUSERPASSWORDS 
    WHERE ISOUID=curIsoUserUID
)
THEN

    BEGIN           <------------ Error is NOT here
        INSERT INTO OLDUSERPASSWORDS(ISOUID, DATECREATE, DATELASTCHANGE, CURRENTPASS, OLDPASS) 
        VALUES(curUserID, userDateCreated, SYSDATE, newUserPwd, oldUserPwd);
    END;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting your first error because you need to add a THEN clause before the BEGIN block to make the syntax of the ID statement complete and correct.

You are getting the second error:

> Error(30,7): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

because you have not completed your INSERT statement. Terminate it with a semicolon and that should fix that error.

```
   IF NOT EXISTS
                (
                  SELECT ISOUID 
                  FROM OLDUSERPASSWORDS 
                  WHERE ISOUID=curIsoUserUID
                )
    THEN     
      BEGIN           
          INSERT INTO OLDUSERPASSWORDS(ISOUID, DATECREATE, DATELASTCHANGE, CURRENTPASS, OLDPASS) 
          VALUES(curUserID, userDateCreated, SYSDATE, newUserPwd, oldUserPwd);
      END;
  END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `THEN` before the `BEGIN`, that goes with the `IF NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: I'm not sure where the then should be?
Looking at this similar situation, there is no THEN?  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971680/sql-server-insert-if-not-exist

Comment: You have an `IF` in `IF NOT EXISTS` so you need a `THEN` to go with it.  You should have a `THEN` on the line before the `BEGIN` where your error is.

Comment: @MOR_SNOW, [that stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971680/sql-server-insert-if-not-exist) is for MSSQL syntax, but you're using PL/SQL here.