# Block data.sql execution

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I set '**spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update**' property in application.properties file, and also am using '**data.sql**' to load some seed-data.

When I run my spring-boot project '**First Time**', all Tables and seed-data loaded to DB.

If I run again my spring-boot project for '**Second Time**', here I need to block execution of '**data.sql**'.

now am getting '**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'** ' because of loaded old seed-data.

Answer (score 0):

One option to make sure that spring-boot does not fail-fast is to set the property: `spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true`.

> By default, Spring Boot enables the fail-fast feature of the Spring
>   JDBC initializer. This means that, if the scripts cause exceptions,
>   the application fails to start. You can tune that behavior by setting
>   spring.datasource.continue-on-error.

That does not solve the issue but should start your application.

Comment: This is working fin now. But my aim is, I don't want to lose my business data. when I modified my seed-data and I did restart my spring-boot project. you any perfect solution here.

Comment: As one more solution can be this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971680/sql-server-insert-if-not-exist)

Comment: @BGNithinMalathesh why would you loose your data?