# Sql insert new tuples in some tables with condition

Tags: sql

I have a database on [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/it/index.html)  and I wish to update some tables at the same time and I wish to rollback if the value already exist in some tables.

- I have thought:

  - trigger: but I don't like (because the server is not mine and so on)
  - **BEGIN** query (to check), insert (if the condition is right) **COMMIT/ROLLBACK** but in this way I kill the concurrency.

Is there another way or trick in order to do it?

I wish to do this:

```
if(value exist) rollback;
else insert;
```

But I have some tables so I wish to do some like that:

```
if(value1 in table 1 not exist && value2 in table2 not exist)
insert;
else rollback
```

Another example:

```
Table1: dog color -> Bobby black - Rex white
Table2: pot misure -> Moon 12 -  Lima 13

insert in table1 dog color  Bobby pink
insert in table2 pot misure Charly 9
```

rollback all because in table1 already exist Bobby

1. In this case I can use begin transaction and rollback:

   - begin
   - transaction  query in order to know if field is egual
   - rollback or
     insert commit

But I wish to find a way like that:

```
insert bla bla if(condition)
```

is it possible?

I have found this:

```
 Insert into Table1 (dog, color) SELECT 'Zulu', 'yellow' WHERE not
 exists (select * from Table1 where dog = 'Zulu')
```

Bu if I have some of these instructions have I use begin and commit?

Comment: Why would you even Insert at first then Check and Rollback later ? I think you should first Check the Validation using whatever your condition on Table B then Only run Update/Insert Query on Table A.

Comment: Anyway, for your condition SQL have Exists operator : 
if exists(select 1 from table where field1 = 1111)
    Insert into table ... . . .
Else
    do your other stuffs

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971680/sql-server-insert-if-not-exist   ?