# mssql nodejs: Using a connection pool throughout a promise chain

Tags: sql, node.js, es6-promise

I am using the mssql library for nodejs to make queries to my Microsoft SQL Database. It first checks if a row exists in the database and if it does, update the values of that row, if not, create a new row. Here is how I have it set up.  When executed, it complains that the variable pool does not exist on lines 35 and 38.

How can I use the pool variable which i got from the first then statement, in the third then statement.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code and not an image of your code. This is easy to do and format properly: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). More folks are likely to respond. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your three latter thens need to be inside your first then. That way the pool is in their scope.

The pattern is:

```
sql.connect(config).then(pool => { 
  pool.request.query().then().then().then();
})
```

Can you not use a "insert if not exists"? This would be atomic and race free. See [SQL Server Insert if not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971680/sql-server-insert-if-not-exist)
If you used this you would only have to handle the case where the row already exists