# How to insert multiple rows into SQL using an Array?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to insert multiple rows into a database if they don't already exist, swapping out one columns value for each insertion. Below is some pseudo code of the goal:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [ChangeReason] FROM BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons WHERE [ChangeReason]= ('Other','Scope Change'))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons]
        ([ChangeReason]
        ,[IsActive]
        ,[CreatedByUser]
        ,[CreatedOn]
        ,[LastUpdatedByUser]
        ,[LastUpdatedOn])
     VALUES
        ( ('Other','Scope Change')      
        ,'true'
        ,'system'
        ,GETDATE()
        ,null
        ,null)
GO
```

In other words, if a row with `ChangeReason='Other'` already exists, nothing will happen. If it does not exist, then it will be inserted with all the other values outlined as above (IsActive=true, etc). This will be repeated for each element in the array : ('Other','Scope Change')

EDIT:

I have written a stored procedure to take care of the dirty work for me. Is it possible to call this automatically for every element in the array? Or do I need X different exec statements?

```
IF EXISTS ( select * from sys.procedures where name='SafeInsert_BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons') begin
    DROP PROC SafeInsert_BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons
end;
GO
create procedure SafeInsert_BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons @Reason varchar(50)
as
begin
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [ChangeReason] FROM BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons WHERE [ChangeReason]= @Reason)
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons]
                ([ChangeReason]
                ,[IsActive]
                ,[CreatedByUser]
                ,[CreatedOn]
                ,[LastUpdatedByUser]
                ,[LastUpdatedOn])
             VALUES
                (@Reason        
                ,'true'
                ,'system'
                ,GETDATE()
                ,null
                ,null);
end;
GO

exec SafeInsert_BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons @Reason='Other';
-- goal: auto-exec for every element in ('Other','Scope Change')
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Are you sure about `[ChangeReason]= ('Other','Scope Change')`? As it is, it's unclear what are you trying to do

Comment: Sami: no it is just pseudo code. Gordon: The column structure is outlined in the attempted insertion. I updated with more info about desired results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Insert if not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971680/sql-server-insert-if-not-exist)

Comment: It is not a duplicate: that link only inserts 1 row whereas I want to insert multiple rows.

Comment: Yes it is, and you don't have 3 rows here.

Comment: So, you're trying to insert two rows having the values `'Other'` and `'Scope Change'` if those two values doesn't exists in your table? @JamesL. If so, then it's very simple, just `INSERT` the data from the results of `RIGHT/LEFT` joining your table with the values and filter by `NULL`

Comment: I think you should read that other question more carefully Sami. Your solution might work but I'm not sure of the performance implications and the maintainability of something like that. I wrote a stored procedure and updated the question about how to use it with the Array portion

Answer (score 2):

SQL doesn't understand arrays, but you can list multiple insert values like below.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons]
        ([ChangeReason]
        ,[IsActive]
        ,[CreatedByUser]
        ,[CreatedOn]
        ,[LastUpdatedByUser]
        ,[LastUpdatedOn])
     VALUES 
        ('Other'        , 'true', 'system', GETDATE(), null, null)
       ,('Scope Change' , 'true', 'system', GETDATE(), null, null)
```

Comment: Again, OP stated in his question _"In other words, if a row with ChangeReason='Other' already exists, nothing will happen. If it does not exist, then it will be inserted..."_ but this will insert the 2 rows even if they exists (only if there is a PK)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pseudo-table using values like so:

```sql
select v.Id, v.Name from (values (1, 'Jason'), (2, 'Tony'), (3, 'Michelle')) v(Id, Name)
```

`v` is any alias you want to give it and you specify the names for the columns in parentheses.  You can combine that with the [MERGE statement](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-merge/) to only insert those rows if they don't exist.

```sql
WITH SOURCE_CTE AS (
  select ChangeReason, IsActive, CreatedByUser, CreatedOn, LastUpdatedByUser, LastUpdatedOn
  from  (values ('Other',        'true', 'system', getdate(), null, null),
                ('Scope Change', 'true', 'system', getdate(), null, null)
  ) tbl (ChangeReason, IsActive, CreatedByUser, CreatedOn, LastUpdatedByUser, LastUpdatedOn)
)
MERGE into dbo.BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons as t
using SOURCE_CTE as s
on    t.ChangeReason = s.ChangeReason
when not matched by target then
  insert (
    ChangeReason,
    IsActive,
    CreatedByUser,
    CreatedOn,
    LastUpdatedByUser,
    LastUpdatedOn
  )
  values
  (
    s.ChangeReason,
    s.IsActive,
    s.CreatedByUser,
    s.CreatedOn,
    s.LastUpdatedByUser,
    s.LastUpdatedOn
  )
```

*** Edit after stored procedure change ***

I'm not sure where your data is coming from and how you're passing it.  First it seemed like it was just in a sql script.  I find things like above handy for config tables, putting a script in the database project post-deploy to make sure values exist.

If using stored procedures, why not just call the stored procedure for each value?

```sql
exec SafeInsert_BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons @Reason='Other';
exec SafeInsert_BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons @Reason='Scope Change';
```

You could create a UDTT and load that with values and pass it to your stored proc:

```sql
create type StringList as table (
  value varchar(256)
);

Create Procedure SafeInsert_BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons @Reasons StringList readonly
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo]. 
 [BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons]
        ([ChangeReason]
        ,[IsActive]
        ,[CreatedByUser]
        ,[CreatedOn]
        ,[LastUpdatedByUser]
        ,[LastUpdatedOn])

        (select 'Other','Scope Change',   
        ,'true'
        ,'system'
        ,GETDATE()
        ,null
        ,null) where NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
           [ChangeReason] FROM 
   BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons WHERE [ChangeReason] IN ('Other','Scope Change'))
```

or you can have a trigger before insert

```
    Create Trigger name before insert
        On 
   BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons
      For each row 
      As
      IIF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT 
               [ChangeReason] FROM 

   BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons 
        WHERE [ChangeReason] IN 
      ('Other','Scope Change'))) >0)
      THEN 
      INSERT...... 
      END IF
      END
```

or you can use a procedure

```
    checkData(ChangeReason IN 
   BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons.
ChangeReason%TYPE) 
      AS
                IIF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
           (SELECT 
                   [ChangeReason] FROM 


   BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons 
            WHERE [ChangeReason] IN 
          ('Other','Scope Change'))) >0)
          THEN 
          INSERT CHANGEREASON...... 
          END IF 
      END
```

Comment: When I try to run that in MS SQL Studio, I get 'incorrect syntax error'

Comment: Is there any line no

Comment: keep in mind the overhead of trigger. It will fire 5 times if you have 5 columns your checking for OR 20 times if you have 20 columns. Something to consider for your design.

Comment: I guess i should have used statement level trigger ill update because it checks for whole data if that exists or not

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons] ([ChangeReason]
    ,[IsActive]
    ,[CreatedByUser]
    ,[CreatedOn]
    ,[LastUpdatedByUser]
    ,[LastUpdatedOn])
SELECT [ChangeReason],'true','system',getDate(),null,null
FROM BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons
WHERE [ChangeReason]in ('Other','Scope Change')
```

[dbo].[BudgetAndAuthorizationChangeReasons] table should exist.

Comment: Thanks! Can you write that to call my stored procedure and I'll accept?

Answer (score -1):

You struggle with the code because you struggle to define your goal. And that bleeds into those trying to help. Given a set of reasons, you simply want to all those that do not already exist in the table.

```
-- declare variables for demo
declare @rsn table (ChangeReason varchar(20) not null primary key, 
IsActive varchar(5) not null, CreatedOn datetime not null);

-- add some "existing" data to table
insert @rsn (ChangeReason, IsActive, CreatedOn) 
values ('Other', 'true', '20190801 13:01:01');

-- demonstrate the use of a table value constructor
with cte as (select * from (values ('Other'), ('Scope'), ('Change')) as x(rsn))
select * from cte;

-- use a transaction for testing just in case you actually use a real table
-- and not a table variable 
begin tran;

merge into @rsn as target
using (values ('Other'), ('Scope'), ('Change')) as source(rsn)
on target.ChangeReason = source.rsn
when not matched by target then
insert (ChangeReason, IsActive, CreatedOn) values (rsn, 'true', getdate())
;

-- verify logic worked correctly
select * from @rsn;

rollback tran;
```

Here is [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ed91282297cd355293d22ab401fe603e) to demonstrate. Notice that this makes use of [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which is a very handy thing to know.