# Insert into mysql table only if those values are not in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have search already an answer but i can't find one that is good for my situation. 
I have a table called Names like this

```
ID NAME   Age 
1  Paula   20 
2  Mark    17
```

And i want to run this sql

```
Insert into table names(name,age) values ("Chriss",15)//should be inserted 

Insert into table names(name,age) values ("Mark",17)// should be ignored 

Insert into table names(name,age) values ("Andrea",20) //should be inserted
```

So how can I ignore second insert query

Comment: You need to define name as `unique`

Comment: > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971680/sql-server-insert-if-not-exist

Answer (score 2):

Create a constraint that demands NAME and Age to be unique in the table.

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`NAME`, `Age`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would either need to Add *UNIQUE* constraint or check the data at the run time (if you don't have a permission to change table schema):

```
ALTER TABLE `Table_name` 
     ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`NAME`, `AGE`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
INSERT INTO names(name,age)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Chriss', 15) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM names WHERE name = 'Chriss' AND age = 15
) LIMIT 1;
```

An other way is just make the columns `name` and `age` UNIQUE so the query fails.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this:

```
Insert into table names(name,age) 
   SELECT "Chriss",15 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM names WHERE `name` = "Chriss");

Insert into table names(name,age) 
   SELECT "Mark",17 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM names WHERE `name` = "Mark");

Insert into table names(name,age) 
   SELECT "Andrea",20 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM names WHERE `name` = "Andrea");
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a unique constraint for the columns `NAME` and `Age`:

```
ALTER TABLE names ADD UNIQUE un_name_age (`NAME`, `Age`);
```

and then use [`INSERT IGNORE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) to insert the rows:

```
Insert ignore into names(name,age) values 
  ("Chriss",15),
  ("Mark",17),
  ("Andrea",20);
```

So if you try to insert a duplicate name the error will just be ignored and the statement will continue with the next row to insert. 
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6KyWv5sQe7PxDTwkBVjWJe/2).
Result:

```
| ID  | NAME   | Age |
| --- | ------ | --- |
| 1   | Paula  | 20  |
| 2   | Mark   | 17  |
| 3   | Chriss | 15  |
| 4   | Andrea | 20  |
```